# Converting a linear program into standard form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods

In especially, I have a question about the demand that if I have $ Ax \leq b$, then I can convert this into $A'x'=b$ for some new $A'$ and $x'$.

I have given the system of equations:
$20x_1+30x_2 \geq 60$, 
$15x_1+3x_2 \geq 15$ and 
$5x_1+10x_2 \geq 20$

If I introduce new variables $s_1,s_2,s_3$ all greater equal zero(that I can add to the vector x to get x' and attach the identity matrix to A in order to get A'), this can be turned into an actual equation. but my question is: whether this variables can be a priori calculated or do I have to leave them unknown in this equation?

Comment: They become new variables in the equivalent problem. So no, you cannot compute their values a priori.